# How to remove Negotiate scheme authentication when I do integrations tests

Tags: c#, .net-core

I try to do integrations tests with WebApplicationFactory, but I get error.

Part of Program.cs:

```
builder.AddNegotiate(options =>
{
    var ldapConnectionsFactory = new LdapConnectionsFactory(domainConfiguration, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LdapConnectionsFactory>());
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) && ldapConnectionsFactory.TryCreate(out var ldapConnection))
    {
        options.EnableLdap(settings =>
        {
            settings.LdapConnection = ldapConnection;
            settings.Domain = domainConfiguration.Domain;
        });
    }
});
```

This code add six services to services array. If I don't add `builder.AddNegotiate`, I don't have problem.

When I try to do test, I get error:

```
Negotiate authentication requires a server that supports IConnectionItemsFeature like Kestrel.
```

TestFile:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AuthControllerTests
{
    readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    
    public AuthControllerTests()
    {
        _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8001/");
    }

    
    [Test]
    public async Task CheckAdminLogIn_SendRequest_ShouldReturnOk()
    {
        // Arrange

        var credentials = new Credentials() { Login = "admin", Password = "admin" }; 

        var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };

        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(credentials, jsonSerializerOptions);            
        
        StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Act

        var response = await _client.PostAsync("api/Auth/login", httpContent);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

    }
}
```

I try remove services in CustomWebApplicationFactory:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
: WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Here I am trying to find and delete Negotiate, but it deletes 4 out of 6 services
            var negotiateHandler = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(NegotiateHandler));
            services.Remove(negotiateHandler);

            List<ServiceDescriptor> servicesForRemove = services.Where(d => d.ServiceType.FullName.Contains("Negotiate")).ToList();

            foreach (var s in servicesForRemove)
            {
                services.Remove(s);
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

It is not removed:
[image]

Is there another way to disable negotiate auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, then added JwtBearer. It works for me

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                List<ServiceDescriptor> servicesForRemove = services.Where(d => d.ServiceType.FullName.Contains("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication")).ToList();

                foreach (var s in servicesForRemove)
                {
                    services.Remove(s);
                }
                

                var buildServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var loggerFactory = buildServiceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

                services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = JwtProvider.CreateTokenValidator(loggerFactory);
                });
            });            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can remove a specific scheme with:

```
internal class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.Configure<AuthenticationOptions>(o =>
            {
                if (o.Schemes is List<AuthenticationSchemeBuilder> schemes)
                {
                    schemes.RemoveAll(s => s.Name == NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    o.SchemeMap.Remove(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is the best.